# Wait until get-request recieve data and localstorage save it

Tags: typescript, angular

Good day. I'm downloading some data from server, but its downloading and then saving taking some time. In result when in subcribe of query for retrieving data route to next component `this.guide.navigate(['/pin']);` called and data complete saving after my app navigate to 'pin'. 
[image]

I want that my app would wait until all data will be recieved from server, all savings are complete and then navigate to 'pin' route. And "time of menu" and "time of token" would be before "IN PIN". 
Angular 2 version is rc 4.

This is part of code where app call another request in "**provideMenu**" in subscribe.

```
this.accessProvider.getToken(this.seller.email, this.seller.password)
                               .subscribe((data => { console.log(data);                                                          
                                                       this.accessProvider.saveAuthToken(data.json().access_token, data.json().expires_in);                                                       
                                                       this.menuProvider.provideMenu();
                                                       this.guide.navigate(['/pin']);                                                                                                       
                                                   }).bind(this),
                                            (err => { console.log("error: " + err); }).bind(this));
```

---

```
provideMenu() {
        let url = "http://193.124.56.19:8069/api/product";
        let headers = new Headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
        this.http.get(url).subscribe((food => { this.saveMenu(food.json()); 
                                                localStorage.setItem('goods', food.json()); }).bind(this), 
                                      err => console.log(err));         
     }

     saveMenu(menu: any) {     
         let targetFoods = new Array<ItemFoodModel>();
         for (let dish = 0; dish < menu.length; dish++) 
             targetFoods.push(new ItemFoodModel(menu[dish].id, menu[dish].uom_id[0], menu[dish].display_name, menu[dish].description_sale,
                                                menu[dish].categ_id[1], menu[dish].list_price, 0, 
                                                menu[dish].image_medium, 3));
                                                //this.makerBoringJob.prepareImage(menu[dish].image_medium), 0));

         localStorage.setItem('menu', JSON.stringify(targetFoods));

         console.log("time of menu: " + JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime().toString()));         
     }
```

Comment: It isn't clear enough what's going on, the screenshot and the description don't give enough details, the code is always more preferable than a description of what it does. Any way, localstorage is synchronous. No extra actions are needed to 'wait' for it, the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @estus I'm sorry, prehaps I even didn't localize my problem correctly. Perhaps problem not in local storage but in get-request inside provide menu. That's why saving complete after navigate to 'pin'.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see. The problem is that a request in `provideMenu` is async, while `navigate` is called synchronously. You need to return an observable or a promise from `provideMenu` and chain it.

Comment: @estus what do you mean by chain it?

Comment: Attaching a new `subscribe`/`then` to returned observable/promise, `this.menuProvider.provideMenu().subscribe(() => this.guide.navigate(['/pin']));`

Comment: @estus Thank you very much.